# dynamic tooltip text d3 when select value change

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I am trying to draw a dynamic  choropleth map

i select the properties to diplay from a selection input
 the property is mapped in a json dataset and is rapresented with the d3 choropleth tecnique

when i try to diplay with an on mouse over tooltip the object value, the property doesn't refresh and the tooltip continue to show the old property's value.

Any suggestions?? My code is below.

Thanks in advance.

```
    var divtool = d3.select("body").append("div")   
                .attr("class", "tooltip")               
                .style("opacity", 0);

        //onchange choropleth
            d3.selectAll(".demosearch").on("change", function () {
                    var t = this.value;

                          if(t  != 'none'){

                                quantize.domain([
                                d3.min(mn_map.features, function(d) { return d.properties[t]; }), 
                                d3.max(mn_map.features, function(d) { return d.properties[t]; })
                                ]);

                                d3.selectAll("#mappa").attr("class", t)
                                svg.selectAll(".comune")
                                   .data(mn_map.features) 
                                   .attr("class",  function(d) { return (quantize(d.properties[t])); })
                                   .style("opacity", 0.8);

                      //Adding mouseevents
                                   .on('mouseover', function (d) {
                                    d3.select(this).transition().duration(100).style({'opacity': 0.8, 'stroke': 'red', "stroke-width": 4  })
                            divtool.text(d.properties.NOME_COM + " : " +t+" : "+ d.properties[t])
                                   .style("opacity", 1) 
                                   .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY -30) + "px");                                          })


                                   .on('mouseout', function (d) {                           d3.select(this).transition().duration(100).style({'opacity': 0.8, 'stroke': '#909090', "stroke-width": 1 });
                                    divtool.style("opacity", 0);
                                  })
                                            }// <-- End if test this.value

                        else {
                         svg.selectAll("#mappa")
                            .transition().duration(500)
                            .attr("class","mappa" )
                         divtool.remove();  
                        };
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to update the tooltip please?

Comment: divtool.text(d.properties.NOME_COM + " : " +t+" : "+ d.properties[t])

Comment: And what exactly do you mean when you say that it doesn't refresh? Does it show the same text for all features, or does it show the same text after you've changed the data?

Comment: it shows the first property values for each zone of the map for the selected text whenever i change the property with the selection. take a look on the url  http://areuexperienced.ns0.it/ and change the the DISTRIBUZIONE DEMOGRAFICA POPOLAZIONE select

Comment: Are you running the code to set the tooltip text when the data is updated?

Comment: divtool.text(d.properties.NOME_COM + " : " +t+" : "+ d.properties[t]) isn't enaugh?

Comment: From what I can see it should work. Could you maybe reduce it to a minimal example that shows the problem?

Comment: i've updated the snippet minimizing the code.

Comment: That should work as far as I can see. Could you put a stand-alone example on something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?